# Magento Join and Left Join function

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

is there anyway that i can join groupdeals/coupon table to my grid collection?
this is my prepare collection function

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{   
    $orderIds = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))->getColumnValues('order_id');  
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_grid_collection')->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $orderIds));

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

now i want it to join with groupon_coupons table
[image: groupon database table]

i want to join the tables so that i can filter Coupon code and security code from my  order Grid.

Comment: there are ways to join two magento tables. Please be clear.

Comment: i want to join my groupdeas_coupon table with my sales_order grid table so i can filter orders by coupon code

Answer (score 0):

add this line to collection  `->join(array('tblalias' => 'tablename'),'main_table.fildname = tblalias.fildname',array('fildfromsecondtable' => 'tblalias.filedname'))`